# Google Sheet Scripts -> ss.getRange() -> JSON.Stringify removing the brackets at the element level for 1 dimension arrays

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

If you want to stringify column A,B,C for a few rows it makes sense that JSON.stringify returns something like [ ["1a","2a","3a"], ["1b","2b", "3b"] ].

However if you are using just one column i.e. a 1 dimensional array, then what JSON.stringify does is terrible:  [ ["1a"], ["1b"] ]

What my API  expects is  ["1a","1b"]

What I am missing?: How can I tell  it to properly format it?

Comment: I apologize for my poor English skill. Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, the result you expect is `console.log(JSON.stringify([["1a", "2a", "3a"], ["1b", "2b", "3b"]].map(([a]) => a)))` or `console.log(JSON.stringify([["1a"], ["1b"]].flat()))`? In this case, both results are the same like `["1a","1b"]`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63720612/what-does-the-range-method-getvalues-return-and-setvalues-accept

Answer (score 2):

From the question

> However if you are using just one column i.e. a 1 dimensional array, then what JSON.stringify does is terrible: [ ["1a"], ["1b"] ]

It looks that you have a misconception, as `getValues()` returns a bi-dimensional no matter if the range refers to a single row or a single column. Anyway, one way to convert the bi-dimentional array into a one-dimension array  is by using `Array.prototype.flat()`.

```js
let column = [[1],[2],[3]]
console.log(column.flat())
```