# Google Sheet AppScript IF statement

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sales report as like below

[image]

I want to take **Sale1person1** data if the **Sale** is **Food Items** and **Sale1person2** if the **Sale** is **Gadget**
and provide that to HTML file line

```
emailTemp.htmlsalevalue=row[???];
```

How to create if statement in emailTemp to get the corresponding data?

```
function myFunction() {
    var sale=9;
    var person1=10;
    var person2=11;
    
    var emailTemp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Table");
    var ws= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 3");
    var data = ws.getRange(ws.getLastRow(),1,1,ws.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    
    data.forEach(function(row){
    
        emailTemp.htmlsale=row[sale];
    
    })
}
```

Comment: Do you  understand JavaScript arrays?

Comment: I am learning it. Is there any possible way for my request please

Comment: It is possible and I'm sure someone will post a readymade answer. In the mean time, try looking into [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Arrays) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63720612/what-does-the-range-method-getvalues-return-and-setvalues-accept) and see if you can figure it out on your own.

Comment: Have you been able to create the if statement with the documentation @TheMaster pointed you to? Also, the html file that is supposed to get the information for the table can you share it as well?