# setValues from array isn't recognizing the data range as 9 columns, when I have assigned 10

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to use `setValues` from an array I have 10 columns of data so `[9]` in the array.  I keep getting an app script error about having 10 columns of the range but only 1 column of data.  I'm seeing 3 `[]` brackets around my array. One set of brackets around the whole array and then two `[]` around each row of data. Not sure if this is the problem.

```
// Search Records for Contact ID Number
function searchExistingCustomers() {
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  //get Active Sheet
const searchSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Search Sheet");   //get Sheet "Search Sheet"
const existingSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Existing Customers"); //get Sheet "Existing Customers"
var lastNameSearch = searchSheet.getRange("B2").getValue(); //last name search string
var columnIndex = 9
var lRow = existingSheet.getLastRow();
var lColumn = existingSheet.getLastColumn();
var columnArray = existingSheet.getRange(2,columnIndex,lRow).getValues(); //Get Values in Array 1st row is header row
var valuesFound=false; //variable to boolean value

// examin the values in the array
var rowSearchValue = 0;
let searchResults = []; 
for (var y = 0; y < lRow; y++) {
   if(columnArray[y] == lastNameSearch){
     var searchRow = (y + 2);
     var searchInfo = existingSheet.getRange(searchRow,1, 1, 10).getValues();
     searchResults.push(searchInfo);
   rowSearchValue = (rowSearchValue +1);
   }
}

//Send Search Results to Search Spreadsheet

searchSheet.getRange(5,1,rowSearchValue,10).setValues(searchResults);

Logger.log(ss);
Logger.log(existingSheet);
Logger.log(existingSheet);
Logger.log(lastNameSearch);
Logger.log(lRow);
Logger.log(lColumn);
Logger.log(columnArray);
Logger.log(rowSearchValue);
Logger.log(searchRow);
Logger.log(searchResults);


}
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63720612/what-does-the-range-method-getvalues-return-and-setvalues-accept

Answer (score 2):

#### Modification points:

- `getValues()` of Class Range returns 2 dimensional array. In your script, `var searchInfo = existingSheet.getRange(searchRow, 1, 1, 10).getValues();` is pushed to an array with `searchResults.push(searchInfo);`. In this case, `searchResults` is 3 dimensional array. I thought that this might be the reason for your issue. When your script is modified by reflecting this, please modify it as follows. By this modification, I think that your error can be removed.

  - From

    ```
      searchResults.push(searchInfo);
    ```
  - To

    ```
      searchResults.push(searchInfo[0]);
    ```
- But, when `getValues` is used in a loop, the process cost becomes high.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function searchExistingCustomers() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  //get Active Sheet
  const searchSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Search Sheet");   //get Sheet "Search Sheet"
  const existingSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Existing Customers"); //get Sheet "Existing Customers"
  var lastNameSearch = searchSheet.getRange("B2").getValue(); //last name search string
  var columnIndex = 9
  var values = existingSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var res = values.reduce((ar, r) => {
    if (r[columnIndex - 1] == lastNameSearch) ar.push(r.splice(0, 10));
    return ar;
  }, []);
  searchSheet.getRange(5, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
}
```

#### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: Thanks so much, Tanaike!  This worked perfectly.  I have no idea how it worked.  LOL but I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
function searchDialog() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const esh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const r = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt('Enter Needle', SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  if (r.getSelectedButton() == SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.OK) {
    const lns = r.getResponseText();
    const hA = esh.getRange(1,1,1,10).getValues()[0];
    const hs = esh.getRange(2, 1, esh.getLastRow() - 1, 10).getValues();
    let html = '<html><head><style>th,td{border:1px solid black;}</style></head><body><table>';
    html += `<tr><th>${hA.join('</th><th>')}</th></tr>`;
    hs.forEach((r, i) => {
      if (r[8] == lns) {
        html+= `<tr><td>${r.join('</td><td>')}</td></tr>`;
      }
    });
    html += '</table></body></html>';
    //Logger.log(html);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html),'Search Result');
  }
}
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much this is perfect.  What code editor are you using?

Comment: The new Apps Script Code Editor