# merging 2 arrays into an array with 2 columns

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to merge 2 arrays in the following format.

```
array1 = [ "a" , "b" , "c"]
array2 = [ 1 , 2 , 3]
merged_array = [ {"a",1} , {"b",2} , {"c",3}]
```

The goal is to use this as values of 2 columns and rewrite this back to google sheet.

is my format correct and if yes how should i merge the arrays as said above ?

EDIT:

i decided to use this

```
var output = [];

for(var a = 0; a <= array1.length; a++)
output.push([array1[a],array2[a]]);
```

how would this compare to map function, performancewise ?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63720612/what-does-the-range-method-getvalues-return-and-setvalues-accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
array1 = [ "a" , "b" , "c"]
array2 = [ 1 , 2 , 3]
merged_array = []
for index, value in enumerate(array1): merged_array.append({value,array2[index]})
print (merged_array)
```

-> [{'a', 1}, {'b', 2}, {'c', 3}]

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: This is not a [tag:python] question.

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisGagnon There's really not much to say about it.  The op showed us what we were starting with and what was wanted.  I struggled to find anything to say..

Answer (score 1):

#### Merging two arrays into and array of arrays

```
function myFunk() {
  let array1 = ["a", "b", "c"];
  let array2 = [1, 2, 3];
  let a = array1.map((e,i) => {return [e,array2[i]];})
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(a));
}

Execution log
4:17:09 PM  Notice  Execution started
4:17:08 PM  Info    [["a",1],["b",2],["c",3]]
```

[Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)