# How can I create a new array and append it to the source array using map + arrow function?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

So I would like to map a resulting value to each row within a `range` of `values`, populate the results into a new array and paste the created array to enrich the source data.

So the callback function in the map method should check if the `amount` is < > 0 and return `revenue` `expense` respectively. I'm struggling in defining the map method and callback function. How can I "access" the amount column? And do I need one or two parameters for the arrow function?

```
function example_function() {

  // Get active Sheet
  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()

  // Get the range
  range = sheet.getDataRange()

  // Get its values
  values = range.getValues()

  // Create new array by mapping the desired results
  resulting_array = values.map((a, b) => {

    // "if value in current row and column b is > 0 then return "revenue", else "expense"
    // what would be the app script language equivalent to this condition?


  });

  // Paste the created array
  sheet.getRange(2, 3).setValues(resulting_array);
}
```

Source

| Item | Amount | P&L |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Shopify | -30 |  |
| Paypal | 40 |  |

Desired Outcome

| Item | Amount | P&L |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Shopify | -30 | Expense |
| Paypal | 40 | Revenue |

Comment: Related:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63720612/what-does-the-range-method-getvalues-return-and-setvalues-accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done many ways. I'd try this:

```
function example_function() {

    // Get active Sheet
    sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  
    // Get the range
    range = sheet.getDataRange()
  
    // Get its values
    values = range.getValues()
  
    // Create new array by mapping the desired results
    resulting_array = values.map(row => row[1] > 0 ? ['Revenue'] : ['Expense']);
  
    // Paste the created array
    sheet.getRange(1,3,resulting_array.length,1).setValues(resulting_array);
}
```