# How to display image from google sheet link (google drive) in web app

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I would like to ask a question about display

This code is working OK to display photo in web app

```
<img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1WkJNdilRDNM2l37fvPHhofYZVUJ20zhy"/>
```

But I want to get ID of picture in google sheet cell

```
<img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=" + data[xx]
```

which id is on the column xx
so how could I write the code.
Thank you.

```
<img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id= +"<?= data[xx]?>"
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63720612/what-does-the-range-method-getvalues-return-and-setvalues-accept

Answer (score 0):

Thank you I already get it

```
<img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=<?=data[10]?>">
```