# Clear cells when checking a checkbox

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, checkbox, triggers

I had this spreadsheet/script combo working perfectly, then made some visual/organization changes, and now it's not and I'm stumped why.

On the 1st sheet 'Filter' the checkbox in G1 is supposed to clear all of the cells in row 3 (which are my filter conditions).

Any pointers what I'm missing are appreciated!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1syLb6XaAWzmDecMzKWP9TpxZrMprYhLxBqQ4E8hTmmM/edit?usp=sharing

I'm not sure if you're able to view the script or not – here's what I've got currently:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.columnStart === 7 && e.range.getValue() === TRUE)
    ClearCells();
}

function ClearCells() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Filter');
 sheet.getRange('A3:F3').clearContent();
}
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72871670/

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `e.range.getValue() === TRUE` by `e.range.getValue() === "TRUE"` or `e.value === "TRUE"`

The default options for checkboxes are strings, `"TRUE"` and `"FALSE"`.

Comment: Thanks! I used function your 2nd option and it worked great.

Comment: They are actually of type Boolean and not strings. The problem is `e.value` always returns a string. So ``e.range.getValue() === "TRUE"`` won't work. This ``e.value === "TRUE"`` will. This `e.range.getValue() === TRUE` doesn't work, because js boolean is `true` and not `TRUE`. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72871670

Comment: @TheMaster Thanks... Should we mark this Q/A As duplicate of the one that pointed as related?

Comment: @Rubén If you don't mind, I think we should.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Filter" && e.range.columnStart == 7 && e.value == "TRUE")
  sh.getRange("A3:F3").clearContent();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That almost worked, but for some reason the script was getting triggered with some other checkboxes I have on the sheet (which do NOT use values of TRUE/FALSE).

The other solution posted here worked for me, so it looks like I'm good to go now.

Comment: All of the default chieckboxes use values "TRUE" and "FALSE" which are strings.  TRUE and FALSE are not boolean values.  Only true and false are boolean values.