# how to write the contents of set/range to a cell in google sheets web app scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, reference, set, save, cell

Code.gs

```
function logHIST(){

//already got sheet assigned.....
var taskITEMS = userORDER.getRange(2,3).getValue();
var entry = [today,username,"",taskITEMS,"","","",periodLABEL,userBASKET];
history.getRange(lastRow+1,1,1,9).setValues([entry]);
}
```

So I get the items alright, but it only write the first item in the set. it writes the other entries, such as the name dates and all; but the TaskITEMS only put the first.
[[a][b][c]]

The log shows that it has the set though.

basically I need store [[a][b][c]]==>A4
Hope this makes sense.
Thanks.

Comment: Using relevant tags ensure your question reaches the proper audience. Your question never reached the intended audience as you missed [google-apps-script] tag.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63720612/what-does-the-range-method-getvalues-return-and-setvalues-accept