# How can you split the the values from getDisplayValues() so that it appears with spaces instead of commas in the textbox popup?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, replace, split

I'd like to have valuesToCopy be separated by a space where the commas are created by getDisplayValues() in the popup so it doesn't appear as one long string. I'm using getDisplayValues() because there are dates that I don't want to change the formatting for.

```
function TextBox() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1JZ-v5n5m0_lyaoLgsHDAa78AtYNP5AsUDo2NRpJbwG4').getSheetByName('HOT WARM CLIENTS');
  sheet.sort(9)
  var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "MM/dd/yy")
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var valuesToCopy = sheet.getRange("D5:J5").getDisplayValues()

var ar2 = [
{
  message: valuesToCopy + "\n\n Did we do work for this client today/yesterday?",
  range: "G5"
}

];

ar2.forEach(({message, range }) => {
  var res = ui.prompt(message, ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  if (res.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.YES) {
    sheet.getRange(range).setValue(res.getResponseText());
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  } else { 
    Logger.log('The user clicked "No" or the dialog\'s close button.');
  }
})
```

I've tried

```
valuesToCopy = valuesToCopy.split(',') 
and I get an error: TypeError: valuesToCopy.split is not a function
```

Comment: `valuesToCopy` is a array. Use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63720612/what-does-the-range-method-getvalues-return-and-setvalues-accept

Comment: so do you wish the 2d array of values to be turned into a flat array of strings?

Comment: Ideally they would appear in a column with the contents of each cell one on top of the other but I'm okay with a flat array of strings as long as there are spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var valuesToCopy = sheet.getRange("D5:J5").getDisplayValues().map(r => r.join(' '));
```

Comment: I should have mentioned I was looking for how to make it a column specifically so I used var valuesToCopy = sheet.getRange("D5:J5").getDisplayValues().map(r => r.join(' \n '));

Comment: How can I change the text size of all the text in the popup?

Comment: If you pop is a SpreadsheetApp.getUi() dialog then you can use css.  If you popup is a toast I don't believe that you can.