# setNumberFormat is not a function?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to change the NumberFormat for all the values into a specific column with app script.
Here is an extract of my code :

```
var range = ss.getRange(2,2,ss.getMaxRows(),1).getValues();
range.setNumberFormat("0");
```

The execution displays the following error : *"TypeError: range.setNumberFormat is not a function"* but I do not understand why.

For your information, when I log my range with :

```
Logger.log(range)
```

Here is the result :

```
[[2.0222117E7], [2.0222004E7], [2.0222004E7], [2.0222003E7], [2.0222002E7], [2.0222001E7], [2.0211004E7], [2.0211003E7], [2.0211002E7], [2.0211001E7], [2.0200004E7], [2.0200003E7], [2.0200002E7], [2.0200001E7], [2.0199001E7],...
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

Because the variable `range` is not a member of  the real class range. It's a  two dimensional array `Array[][]`. Only real Range objects have methods like `setNumberFormat`.

```
const range =/*This is a range*/ ss.getRange(2,2,ss.getMaxRows(),1);
const values = /*This is not a range*/range.getValues();
range.setNumberFormat("0");
```

Related: [What does the range method getValues() return and setValues() accept?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63720612/what-does-the-range-method-getvalues-return-and-setvalues-accept)