# Arrays and "The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues." error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have this code (it's pasted just a portion)

```
var valores = [[FACTURA.getRange(CELDA_NRO_FACTURA).getValue(),  //Nro Factura
                 FACTURA.getRange(CELDA_FECHA).getValue(),   //Fecha
                 FACTURA.getRange(CELDA_MEDIO_PAGO1).getValue(),   //Medio de pago
                 FACTURA.getRange(CELDA_DTO_RGO_GENERAL).getValue(),   //Dto/Rgo general
                
                //Fila 6
                 FACTURA.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA,PRIMERA_COLUMNA).getValue(),  //Código
                 FACTURA.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA,PRIMERA_COLUMNA + 1).getValue(),  //Cantidad
                 FACTURA.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA,PRIMERA_COLUMNA + 2).getValue(),  //Descripción
                 FACTURA.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA,PRIMERA_COLUMNA + 7).getValue(),  //Unitario
                 FACTURA.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA,PRIMERA_COLUMNA + 8).getValue(),  //Dto/Rgo x fila

                //Fila 7
                 FACTURA.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA + 1,PRIMERA_COLUMNA).getValue(),  //Código
                 FACTURA.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA + 1,PRIMERA_COLUMNA + 1).getValue(),  //Cantidad
                 FACTURA.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA + 1,PRIMERA_COLUMNA + 2).getValue(),  //Descripción
                 FACTURA.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA + 1,PRIMERA_COLUMNA + 7).getValue(),  //Unitario
                 FACTURA.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA + 1,PRIMERA_COLUMNA + 8).getValue(),  //Dto/Rgo x fila


                //Fila 8
                 FACTURA.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA + 2,PRIMERA_COLUMNA).getValue(),  //Código
                 FACTURA.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA + 2,PRIMERA_COLUMNA + 1).getValue(),  //Cantidad
                 FACTURA.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA + 2,PRIMERA_COLUMNA + 2).getValue(),  //Descripción
                 FACTURA.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA + 2,PRIMERA_COLUMNA + 7).getValue(),  //Unitario
                 FACTURA.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA + 2,PRIMERA_COLUMNA + 8).getValue(),  //Dto/Rgo x fila

                //Fila 9
                 FACTURA.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA + 3,PRIMERA_COLUMNA).getValue(),  //Código
                 FACTURA.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA + 3,PRIMERA_COLUMNA + 1).getValue(),  //Cantidad
                 FACTURA.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA + 3,PRIMERA_COLUMNA + 2).getValue(),  //Descripción
                 FACTURA.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA + 3,PRIMERA_COLUMNA + 7).getValue(),  //Unitario
                 FACTURA.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA + 3,PRIMERA_COLUMNA + 8).getValue(),  //Dto/Rgo x fila

                //Fila 10
                 FACTURA.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA + 4,PRIMERA_COLUMNA).getValue(),  //Código
                 FACTURA.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA + 4,PRIMERA_COLUMNA + 1).getValue(),  //Cantidad
                 FACTURA.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA + 4,PRIMERA_COLUMNA + 2).getValue(),  //Descripción
                 FACTURA.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA + 4,PRIMERA_COLUMNA + 7).getValue(),  //Unitario
                 FACTURA.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA + 4,PRIMERA_COLUMNA + 8).getValue(),  //Dto/Rgo x fila

                FACTURA.getRange(CELDA_OBSERVACIONES).getValue()  //Observaciones

                 ]];

  
datos.getRange(datos.getLastRow()+1,1,1,55).setValues(valores);
```

and i want to change it by this code

```
var valores = [factura.getRange(CELDA_NRO_FACTURA).getValue(),  //Nro Factura
                 factura.getRange(CELDA_FECHA).getValue(),   //Fecha
                 factura.getRange(CELDA_MEDIO_PAGO1).getValue(),   //Medio de pago
                 factura.getRange(CELDA_DTO_RGO_GENERAL).getValue(),   //Dto/Rgo general
                 factura.getRange(CELDA_OBSERVACIONES).getValue()]  //Observaciones
  
Logger.log(valores)

const COLUMNA_CODIGO = 3
const COLUMNA_CANTIDAD = 4
const COLUMNA_DESCRIPCION = 5
const COLUMNA_UNITARIO = 10
const COLUMNA_DTO_RGO = 11
const CANT_FILAS_FACTURA = 10
var cont = 5
  
for(fila=0;fila < CANT_FILAS_FACTURA; fila++){
  valores.push(factura.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA + fila,COLUMNA_CODIGO).getValue())  //Código
  valores.push(factura.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA + fila,COLUMNA_CANTIDAD).getValue())  //Cantidad
  valores.push(factura.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA + fila,COLUMNA_DESCRIPCION).getValue())  //Descripción
  valores.push(factura.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA + fila,COLUMNA_UNITARIO).getValue())  //Unitario
  valores.push(factura.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA + fila,COLUMNA_DTO_RGO).getValue())  //Dto/Rgo x fila
  }

Logger.log(valores)
datos.getRange(datos.getLastRow()+1,1,1,55).setValues(valores);
```

My problem is that I am a beginner and I don't know how to assign the values to the "values" variable in the for. I think they are added with push, but when I run it it gives me the following error:

Exception: The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues.

@Cooper Here it is a minimal reproducible example

```
function Save(){
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var bill = activeSheet.getSheetByName("FACTURA");
  var data = activeSheet.getSheetByName("Datos_Facturas");
  
  var values = [[bill.getRange("K3").getValue(),
                 bill.getRange("J3").getValue(),
                 bill.getRange("D3").getValue(),
                 bill.getRange("L17").getValue(),
                 bill.getRange("D17").getValue()]]
  
  Logger.log(values)
 
  for(row=0;row < 10; row++){
    values.push(bill.getRange(6+row,3).getValue())
    values.push(bill.getRange(6+row,4).getValue())
    values.push(bill.getRange(6+row,5).getValue())
    values.push(bill.getRange(6+row,10).getValue())
    values.push(bill.getRange(6+row,11).getValue())
  }

  Logger.log(values)
  data.getRange(data.getLastRow()+1,1,1,55).setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: Which assignment for valores are you using.  Please provide a complete [mcve]

Comment: Between being half spanish and half english and not very well organized it's hard to tell what's going on with your code.

Comment: Do you see that you have changed the type of your valores variable ?  In the original code, you used two square brackets `var valores = [[FACTURA` (so a two-dimensional array, which is what `setValues` accepts), but in your second code you only have a single square bracket `var valores = [factura`, so it is now just a simple one-dimensional array.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63720613

Comment: @racraman it didn't work –

Comment: Define “didn’t work” - same error ?   Did you update the rest of the code in line with charging the type ?

Comment: @racraman yes, same error.
I don't understand _with charging the type_. I'm beginner, sorry.
I copied a minimal reproducible example below.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For this table:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 |
| 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 |

The data array looks like this:

```
[["COL1","COL2","COL3","COL4","COL5"],
[1,2,3,4,5],
[2,3,4,5,6],
[3,4,5,6,7],
[4,5,6,7,8],
[5,6,7,8,9],
[6,7,8,9,10],
[7,8,9,10,11],
[8,9,10,11,12],
[9,10,11,12,13]]
```