# How to cross-check data in Google Sheets, with Google App Scripts?

Tags: javascript, validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm going MAD oaks, please help, this code is meant for cross-checking data in Google Sheets, so essentially we're comparing column A (which has the company names), and column B (which has the urls), and output the data in column A into column C as sourceName:"company name".

**Here is an exmaple of the layout:**

| Column A (Company Name) | Column B (url) | Column C (sourceName:"") |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bloomberg | [www.Bloomberg.com](http://www.Bloomberg.com) | sourceName:"Bloomberg" |
| ENCA | [www.ENCA.com](http://www.ENCA.com) | sourceName:"ENCA" |
| Nikkei | [www.Nikkei.com](http://www.Nikkei.com) | sourceName:"Nikkei" |

Column C would be empty, and populated by the scripts as sourceName:"name of company"

**Here is the code**

```
function matchAndOutput() {
  // Get the active sheet in the Google Sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  // Get the values from the entire data range in the sheet
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // Iterate through each row in the data
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    // Check if the cell contents are a string
    if (typeof data[i][0] === 'string') {
      // Split the cell contents into sourceName and URL
      var cellContents = data[i][0];
      var parts = cellContents.split('\t');

      // Check if parts has at least two elements
      if (parts.length >= 2) {
        var sourceName = parts[0].trim();
        var url = parts[1].trim(); // Extract URL from the cell contents

        // Check if sourceName and URL don't match
        if (sourceName !== url) {
          // Set an orange background for the entire row
          sheet.getRange(i + 1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).setBackground('orange');
        } else {
          // If they match, set the value in column C with the desired output
          sheet.getRange(i + 1, 3).setValue('sourceName:"' + sourceName + '"');
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The code runs, but nothing happens in the actual sheets as well, what am I doing wrong please.

I tried Bard, ChatGPT, and scoured YT and GitHub for answers.

Comment: Explain `cellContents.split('\t');`

Comment: I used the JS 'split' method to divide the contents of the variable cellContents into an array of substrings based on the specified delimiter, which is the tab character ('\t'). So it splits the string into an array using the tab character as the delimiter. For example, it would create an array like ["University of Pretoria", "www.up.com"]. After splitting the string, the following code assumes that the first element (parts[0]) contains the source name, and the second element (parts[1]) contains the URL.

Comment: Which column is this acting on? If ``A2``, what would happen to `Bloomberg`

Comment: That's how it would look after being populated by the script, so column C would be empty before running the scripts. A2 would get copied into C2 wrapped in 'sourceName:" "'

Comment: Where is the tab character `\t` in your sheet or your example? Do you understand what the code is doing? It's looking for that character in  columnA's cells. Based on your sample, I cannot find such a character.

Comment: I'm a jr, so my code structure can be a bit shaky sometimes, I changed it to `var parts = cellContents.split(' ');` and it -somewhat- worked! Thank you so much, do you have any other tips/advice please?

Comment: Your sample doesn't have a space character either. Where is `' '` in `Bloomberg` or `ENCA`? Is  the sample representative of your actual sheet data? If not, [edit] to provide representative data.

Comment: Yes, its representative of the actual data I'm working with.

Comment: Then why are you splitting by space or any character, when there's no such character in Col A? Review https://stackoverflow.com/a/63720613/ Check Col B, split by `.`. Do NOT use AI tools such as chatGPT/Bard. Try to I understand and think for yourself, then practice, practice and practice.