# Custom function not accepting arrays properly

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula, custom-function

I am trying to write a custom Apps Script Code.gs function. The function is supposed to accept an array parameter from Google Sheets, do some math with it, and then output the number. I am having trouble getting it to accept the array.

For the function:

```
function Prodmult(legs){
    return legs.length;
};
```

When I call in in Google Sheets with
`=Prodmult({1,2,3})`
The cell returns 1

How can I handle the array argument properly? I ultimately want to multiply all the numbers in the array together, which is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

`{1,2,3}` translates to `[[1,2,3]]` in JavaScript. The length of `[[1,2,3]]` is `1`. The length of `[[1,2,3]][0]` is `3`.

`{1;2;3}` translates to `[[1],[2],[3]]` in JavaScript. The length of `[[1],[2],[3]]` is `3`. The length of `[[1],[2],[3]][0]` is `1`.

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63720613/) for a more detailed explanation on arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=Prodmult(JOIN(,{1,2,3})
```

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077?hl=en about JOIN for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Apps Script interprets `Prodmult({1,2,3})` as `Prodmult([[1,2,3]])`. So your function needs to handle a two-dimensional array.

```
function Prodmult(legs){
    return legs[0].length;
};
```