# why does this return a function?(javascript)

Tags: javascript

I got a little bit of code that i can't quite wrap my head around.
It's for a function that handles an onClick event in javascript/react:

```
handleButtonClick(key, song) {
    return () => {
        document.getElementById(key).play();
        this.setState({
            currentSongText: song,
        });
    };
}
```

Now I don't get why it does return () =>{} inside the body of handleButtonClick, but if I remove it, the code no longer works?
I found nothing while googling this so any advice is welcome.

link to the project: https://codepen.io/koffiekan/pen/eYJqdWW

Comment: Apparently this method is expected to return a callback function.  Why that is, would be up to how this method is used.

Comment: Put the code where the handler is bounded to the event, my guess would be it is:
Onclick = handleButtonClick(value,value);

Comment: Given that the method name is `handleButtonClick`, one would expect there is some usage such as `someButton.addEventListener('click', handleButtonClick('somekey', 'somesong'))`

Comment: @koffiekan I have an idea of what is your problem, regarding context access between fat arrow and regular functions, but I agree the question is too incomplete to provide an accurate answer. Would you mind sharing how you use the callback in your render method?

Comment: hi all, he the link to the project: https://codepen.io/koffiekan/pen/eYJqdWW

Answer (score 0):

This is called a callback. Here is a stackoverflow post on how they work. [What is a callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824234/what-is-a-callback-function)

onclick events are expecting a function, this is so that it can point or reference at the function when the event handler fires and does not need to copy the entire function - it allows the re-usability of the code.

Comment: Callbacks have the form `function outer(callback){ callback(); }`. The code in the question is just a function that returns another function; it doesn’t call it.