# google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function) not returning data

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-workspace

I'm working with G-suite and using "google.script.run" function. I can't fetch or set data out of the function that get's me data to client from server...I can set data to DOM for #myId and check that but I'd like to do it on background...any idea why is this not working?

```
function Class(){
  this.data = false;

  this.getData = function(){
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(helper).getData();
      function helper(data){
        $('#myId').html('data'); // => works...
        this.data = data; // => does not work...
        return data; // => does not work...
      }
  }

  this.submitData = function(){
    if(this.data === false){
      alert('no data');
    }
    else{
      ...code...
    }
  }

  this.run = function(){
    this.getData();
    this.submitData(); // => always get false;
  }
}
```

I need to be able to set this.data with with regular data...or atleast return them from this.getData()

UPDATE

I've got

```
this.getData = function(){
  var testOuput = 'give me test';
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(helper).getData();
      function helper(data){
        testOuput = 'give me something else';
      }
  return testOutput;   
}

this.run {
  alert(this.getData());
}

this.run() // => runs on button click
```

My output is always "give me test" It looks like helper function is not able to access GLOBAL SCOPE variables...

Comment: What is the output if you `console.log(this)` inside the helper function? It could point to a different object so try the following: `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(helper.bind(this)).getData();`

Comment: You need to wait until data is retrieved.

Comment: @Reyno - nope did not help...

Comment: *My output is always "give me test"* How are you getting the output?

Comment: Maybe youR Successhandler never gets called because the Apps Script function getData() fails? Implete a FailureHandler to verify. Also, provide the code of getData() for troubleshooting if you think this might be the cause of the issue

Comment: Issue is the same as said in my answer. At  the time ``helper`` function is called, `getData` has finished running. Read my answer until you get  what it means. Read all the answers in the linked references until you're clear with "callback"s.

Comment: @ziganotschka If the issue was "server" function failure, `$('#myId').html('data');` shouldn't have worked.

Comment: @theMaster True, I skipped this bit.

Comment: where's your doGet?

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue:

Time difference or Async nature of `google.script.run`: At the time, `submitData` executes, `this.data` is `false`, because `getData()`  hasn't finished executing.

```
                                                 ➚ Server executes `getData()` => Calls `helper(datafromServer)` after execution 
                                               ➚  
`this.run` => `this.getData()` => Server called with `google.script.run` and  returns void immediately 
                                                (Client will not wait for server/async) 
                                               ➘ `this.submitData()` called => `helper()` hasn't finished executing. `this.data` is still false
```

#### Solution:

Call `this.submitData()` after `helper` is called.

#### Snippet:

```
  function helper(data){
    $('#myId').html('data'); // => works...
    this.data = data; 
    this.submitData();// => works
  }
```

#### References:

- [What is a callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824234/what-is-a-callback-function)
- [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-)

Comment: I understand what you mean but this is not the case...maybe it's my bad that I put to function run both of the functions but in reality I run function getData before at least a minute to read them in fact I can see them on screen been saved in DOM...user manipulate on client site with this data and after maybe a minute I run submit function...

Comment: @Orbit Could you edit your question to provide a [mcve]?