# jquery - button is hovered after scrollBy

Tags: jquery, button, scroll

```js
$("button").on("click", () => {
    console.log($("button").is(":hover"));
  window.scrollTo(0,0);
  console.log($("button").is(":hover"));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button style="margin-top:600px;">
CLICK
</button>
```

```
// method called on button click

showTab(n) {
    this.tabs.each((idx, tab) => {
        $(tab).hide();
    });

    $(this.tabs[n]).show();
    this.currentTab = parseInt(n);
    window.scrollBy(-100, -100);
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
}
```

at the end of that code the NextButton.is(":hover") returns true, it shows also in button style. I cannot figure out why. Any ideas? Is there a way to "unhover" the button with jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function calls are asynchronous. Therefore immediatly after calling `scrollTo(..)` the `console.log(..)` gets executed while still hovering the button.

To circumvent this behaviour you would usually use a [callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824234/what-is-a-callback-function), that gets called after your initial function has finished.

```js
$("button").on("click", function(){
  console.log($("button").is(":hover"));
  $('html').animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  }, 500, function() {
     // gets executed after the animation has finihsed
     console.log($("button").is(":hover"));
  });
  
})
```

```css
button {
  position:absolute;
  top: 650px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>
  CLICK
</button>
```